# how to pick the column with the highest value

Tags: sql, sas

I have a table with different possibilities of marital status (columns), how do I pick up the one with the highest value and keep the column name?

For example, below is my original data set:

```
data test;
infile datalines missover;
INPUT ID Gender $ pct_married pct_common_law pct_single; 
datalines;
1 male 0.5 0.3 0.2
2 female 0.6 0.4
3 male 0.3 0.3 0.4
;
```

and what i want to see is

```
data test2;
infile datalines missover;
INPUT ID Status $ pct_married pct_common_law pct_single; 
datalines;
1 pct_married
2 pct_married
3 pct_single
;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make an array of the variables to search. Use the MAX() function to find the maximum value. Then using the WHICHN() function to find the index into the array where that value first occurs. Then use the VNAME() function to convert the array reference into the name of the variable.

```
data want ;
  set test;
  array pct pct_: ;
  name = vname(pct[whichn(max(of pct[*]),of pct[*])]);
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `proc sql` and a `case` expression:

```
proc sql;
    select (case when pct_married >= greatest(pct_common_law, pct_single)
                 then 'pct_married'
                 when pct_common_law >= pct_single
                 then 'pct_common_law'
                 else 'pct_single'
            end) as which_is_biggest
    from missover;
```